# Does this sentence make sense? "His father came here to his rescue."

Tags: phrasal-verbs, idioms

I saw this sentence on the internet.
I wonder how I interpret this sentence.

"His father came here to his rescue."
Please, let me know the meaning of this sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Yes,  phrases such as **to come to someone's aid** and similar ones, like your example, "to come to his rescue",  are idiomatic.  The basic meaning is that someone moves or takes action to help or to offer some needed assistance.

> The boy scout came to the old woman's aid as she was crossing the busy
>   street.
>
> When the platoon was pinned down under enemy fire, a fighter jet came
>   to their rescue.
>
> My phone's battery died, but a fellow passenger came to my aid and lent me his phone so I could phone home and say that the train would be stalled on the tracks for an hour or more because of "police activity".

Answer (score 0):

To ***[come to someone's rescue](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/come-to-someone-s-rescue)*** is a common idiomatic expression meaning:

> - to help someone out of a bad situation, as in:
>
>   - *I was about to drop a huge tray of dishes when Brad came to my rescue*

Cambridge Dictionary

Note that the expression may refer  to a physical rescue but is often used in a figurative way.

> - *Thank goodness the lifeguard came to my rescue; otherwise, I might have drowned! Thanks for the notes! You totally came to my rescue after I missed so many classes*.

The Free Dictionary